# Can one break stackrel text into multiple lines?

Tags: stacking-symbols

I'm writing something up where I want to be explicit about some elementary operations I'm performing. I have an arrow between matrices with some text above the arrow showing what I'm doing. The text above the arrow is quite long, is it possible to cause a line break of some sort in stackrel?

My code is the following:

```
\stackrel{R2:= R2-2R1,\ R3:= R3+2R1}{\longrightarrow}
```

Comment: Could you show how you intend to use it? Perhaps even including some mock-up of the expected output.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`\substack` or `subarray` are your friends.

I suggest two commands, one for centered alignment of the elementary operation denotations, one for left alignment, that you might prefer.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\elem}[1]{% elementary operations
  \xrightarrow{\substack{#1}}%
}

\newcommand{\lelem}[1]{% elementary operations (left alignment)
  \xrightarrow{\begin{subarray}{l}#1\end{subarray}}%
}

\begin{document}

\[
\elem{R2:= R2-2R1,\\ R3:= R3+2R1}\quad
\lelem{R2:= R2-2R1,\\ R3:= R3+2R1}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

There's no need to have multiple lines: `\elem{R2:=R2-2R1}` would work seamlessly.

Answer (score 4):

What is wrong with `substack`?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
  $\stackrel{\substack{R2:= R2-2R1,\\ R3:= R3+2R1}}{\longrightarrow}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The first is of course wrong.

Comment: The vertical alignment will be completely wrong.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps a combination of `\overset` and `\shortstack`?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
\overset{\shortstack{$\scriptstyle R2:= R2-2R1$,\\ $\scriptstyle R3:= R3+2R1$}}{\longrightarrow}\quad
\overset{\shortstack[l]{$\scriptstyle R2:= R2-2R1$,\\ $\scriptstyle R3:= R3+2R1$}}{\longrightarrow}
 \]

\end{document}
```

[image]

The optional argument for `\shortstack` allows you to control the alignment.